# What is Hosted Staking?

Tags: financial-literacy, peer-to-peer-lending, lending

There are few ICOs are using Hosted staking as a term rather Lending.

I want to understand what is this hosted staking and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer, when people invent new financial terms, is "a scam". Even for new financial terms that aren't necessarily scams, the abuse of this term (especially to the general public) is a good sign of a scam. And that's before considering crypto.

Just avoid.